# MySQL query with date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query, but it gives me errors, if anyone could give me a hint, would be awesome.

```
SELECT tblinvoices.*,companyname FROM tblinvoices INNER JOIN tblclients 
ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.clientid 
WHERE 1=1 AND date between '20111201' to '20111208'
```

The error message is:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'TO '20111208''

Comment: what's the data type of your date field?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the error message for you. Next time try not to be so lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `AND` instead of `TO` in the `BETWEEN` command.

```
SELECT tblinvoices.*,companyname FROM tblinvoices INNER JOIN tblclients 
ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.clientid 
WHERE 1=1 AND date between '20111201' AND '20111208'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure is the word TO, it should be:

SELECT tblinvoices.*,companyname FROM tblinvoices INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.clientid WHERE 1=1 AND date between '20111201' **AND** '20111208'

Answer (score 0):

If companyname is from tblinvoices it should work, otherwise you need to check where companyname comes from. And the syntax for between is like this

```
date between '20111201' and '20111208'
```